# how to persist column filter in ag-grid vuejs

Tags: ag-grid

I have applied filter property in default column

```
this.defaultColDef = {
    editable: true,
    floatingFilter: true,
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    suppressClickEdit: true,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true,
    filterParams: {newRowsAction: 'keep'}
  }
```

the filter is working fine but when I'm performing rowclicked event and then return to the page , I observed the filter is removed ...

```
onRowClicked(params) { 
  const model = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel()
  this.selectItem(params.node.data) 
  this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(model)
  //this.gridApi.redrawRows()
},
```

and above onrowClicked event will open the details of particular row (basically another page)

so my question is how to persist column filter.

Comment: could you please show the usage of filter in columns?

Comment: @ChiranjhiviGhimire----column take value that we can select or deselect ..e.g one column that's name ia STATUS that have open , close etc value ..and according to user they select the row that contain may be open may be close or both .....